# How to return selected fields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can we limit the fields for each object that is being sent?
Currently my response for each record is

```
{
            "_id": "614822f6badd4d55c8adcb6z",
            "name": "My life",
            "title": "lorem.....",
            "createdBy": "614593516c6a19d614971cae",
            "class": "613f23b026848c8934ffb52l",
            "createdAt": "2021-09-20T05:58:14.200Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-20T07:38:57.160Z",
            "__v": 0,
        }
```

However for each object I only want to name and class only

Comment: Have you checked out the official MongoDB document on [how to return specific fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com) then you can use  projection option like

```
Model.find({}, 'name title'); // will return only _id, name, title
```

Ref: [Model.find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find)